# How can i use underline and bold together dynamicly in java(with using Map for underline)?

Tags: java

How can I use underline and bold together in Java(with using Map for underline)?
I have the following code but when I press bold my underline went away and when I press underline my bold went away.

```
Font font = textField.getFont();
Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
textField.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

Comment: please when u don't know answer of me don`t put negative

Comment: When you know how to ask you will get positive

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna I don't think discouraging new users is what we want to do. Editing and helping to make the question more clear is much more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when i press bold my underline went when i press underline my bold went

Making a wild guess here that you are acutally using a GUI with buttons of mrenu items to set the attributes of some selected text.

If so, then read the section from the swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for a working example that shows  you how to use `Actions` to change text attributes.

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem.